# Is it possible to choose an arbitrary target class when moving instance method in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, refactoring

IntelliJ Idea allows to move method of class to another class (`Refactor -> Move` or `F6`). But it seems that a target class can be chosen only from a limited subset of classes whose objects are encapsulated into a source class.

E.g.

**Source class:**

```
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    private UserService userService;
    private GooglePlayManager googlePlayManager;
    private AndroidPurchasesDBService db;
    private Analytics analytics;
```

**Move Instance Method popup:**

[image]

Is there a way to pick up an arbitraty target class?

Comment: Please follow/comment already created feature request for it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-70207

Comment: @OlgaKlisho thank you!